# Spring Cloud Gateway Filter Factory for Fire and Forget Model

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

I am exploring **Spring Cloud Gateway** filterfactory that can accept a request and return SUCCESS http status to caller. After that, forward it to destination based on the filter factory configuration.

```
caller ---> Spring Cloud Gateway
      <--- Request accepted 
           Spring Cloud Gateway  ---> Destination
```

I didn't find any solution for this in [Spring doc](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Greenwich.SR3/single/spring-cloud.html#_gatewayfilter_factories). Are there any existing filter factory to implement this model? if no then any suggestions how to solution this?

Note: The reason why we want to break the communication at Spring Cloud Gateway is that the Destination server response time is very high and caller can't wait for that long duration.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So in general the solution could be next.
You need to redirect call to some endpoint which will put request for future processing etc.
This part can be implemented using JMS approach it could be any implementation like ActiveMQ ,RabbitMQ etc. You should chose broker according to your needs and expectations.

When request comes from gateway  you redirect on endpoint and simple put message on queue , another service will listen the messages from those queue and will process them.

Another one approach is to use sprint batch job to process some logic etc .
When client make a call it passes through gateway , then gateway will forward request to microservice endpoint and then you store request on database, and return client 202.
Then using batch job via cron process logic.

Benefits of using first approach are lose coupling between microservices,asynchronous processing, and easy to scale.

With spring batch job or any scheduler there would be difficulties at scaling as you need somehow to run only one job at time across several instances . To solve this problem you can use schedlock library.

In case of retry policy of processing when request was accepted MOM(message oriented middleware ) will be easier in case if transaction is failed it has some retry configurations for it .

Using spring batch jobs you need to manage state of request in database and don’t run request with state “processed” etc.